# Kotlin unable to access delegated method via reflection: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"

Tags: kotlin, reflection, delegation

I'm trying to understand how reflection with works with delegation and I've come up with a toy example.

```
class Foo(val m: MutableList<Any>) : MutableList<Any> by m{
}



fun fooAdd(f: Foo) {
    val a = f::class.java.getMethod("add").invoke(f, 20);
    println(a)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fooAdd(Foo(mutableListOf()))
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Foo.add()
```

I'm not sure I understand why it's happening, seeing as  `add()` is delegated to `Foo` from `MutableList` if I understand correctly.

How do I fix this error? Also, is there a library one ought to use for such a use-case?

Answer (score 5):

[`Class#getMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) accepts two parameters:

1. name of a method.
2. Parameter types (vararg of `Class<?>`es).

[`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) has no `add` method without parameters so you're getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

You meant to get method like this:

```
clazz.java.getMethod("add", Any::class.java)
```

Full listing:

```
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val clazz = MutableList::class
    val method = clazz.java.getMethod("add", Any::class.java)
    method.invoke(list, 10)
    println(list)
}
```

Output:

```
[10]
```